# PHP-Event/SSL: Getting client certificate using PHP Event

Tags: php, events, ssl, certificate

I'm using PHP Event as a SSL Server (http://php.net/manual/en/book.event.php - server loosely based upon example #4 at http://php.net/manual/en/event.examples.php#example-4779 ) to handle connections from another application, but I'm looking into the idea of extracting the client certificate so I can disallow those I don't want.

But, I have no idea on how I can implement the function openssl_x509_fingerprint, and I've check all the classes that PHP-Event has, but none is about the client certificate - so I'm reaching out here as a last resort.

Does anyone know how I can get the client certificate using a PHP-Event context (or a EventBuffer)?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Anton

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get in contact with the developers of pecl-event, and they're looking into a solution for this problem. :)